# Python code snippet is taking very long time to run.. how to increase efficiency?

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

The task is to select elements from a list(li) so that the sum is as close to a given number(m) as possible!. But, The idk method is taking a very long time to run: it never completes. When I compile the code, the method just keeps on running and running.

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

def idk(typeOfSlices, maxNoOfPizzaSlices):
    length = len(typeOfSlices) + 1
    listToReturn = []
    temporarySum = 0

    for r in range(length):

        pool = tuple(typeOfSlices)
        n = len(pool)
        for indices in permutations(range(n), r):
            if sorted(indices) == list(indices):
                le = tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
                ts = sum(le)
                if(ts == maxNoOfPizzaSlices):
                    print(le, ":", sum(le))
                    return le

                if(ts > temporarySum and ts <= maxNoOfPizzaSlices):
                    temporarySum = ts
                    listToreturn = le

    print(le, ":", sum(le))
    return listToReturn

m = 4500
li = [7, 12, 12, 13, 14, 28, 29, 29, 30, 32, 32, 34, 41, 45, 46, 56, 61, 61, 62, 63, 65, 68, 76, 77, 77, 92, 93, 94, 97, 103, 113, 114, 114, 120, 135, 145, 145, 149, 156, 157, 160, 169, 172, 179, 184, 185, 189, 194, 195, 195,
]
idk(li, m)
```

Comment: Have you tried running it on a very small input? Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents...

- Does the code snippet work for a smaller array size?  If it doesn't work for a smaller list, then you may have a bad algorithm.
- This may be a good match for multithreading.  You are not modifying the input list, thus there won't be any race conditions.  Slice the list up like you do with the first for-loop, then have each thread handle the permutations.
- You sort the list, then look for a repeated value every time you compute a permutation.  Even worse, you don't even save the sorted list.  I would create a dedicated data structure to store the intermediate results so you can reduce the amount of sorting and hashing required.